# Tyscript PHP HTTP get value

Tags: php, typescript, http

PHPcode

```
 <?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $da = array(
        array('id' => '1','first_name' => 'thia'),
        array('id' => '2','first_name' => 'ithaa')
    );
    echo json_encode($da);
    ?>
```

app.Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    data = [];
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.http.get('http://localhost/php/test.php').subscribe(data => {
      this.data.push(data);
      console.log(this.data);
      }, error => console.error(error));
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let mydata of data[0]">
    <td>{{mydata.id}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It is not working....
Use HTTP get PHP data
If PHP data are arrays how to use HTTP get the data to the page.

Comment: Show the typescript code that you have tried

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try This.

`let msg = '<?php echo $a; ?>';`